# Impossible to install bcrypt with npm on EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, npm

On an Ubuntu Server 14.04 on an Amazon EC2 instance, I had an error when doing `npm install`. It failed to install bcrypt (`"bcrypt": "^0.8.1"`in my `package.json`).

Here's the error I had:

```
> bcrypt@0.8.1 install /home/ubuntu/app/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-gyp rebuild

child_process: customFds option is deprecated, use stdio instead.
make: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/app/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o] Error 127
make: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/app/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/ubuntu/node-v0.12.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1067:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-44-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/home/ubuntu/node-v0.12.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ubuntu/app/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had to install the build tools `sudo apt-get install build-essential g++`

Note that you have to `apt-get update` to avoid any problem with apt-get on EC2 (otherwise you might end up with `E: Failed to fetch…`

Then `npm install` again and you're good to go!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by installing and compiling with gcc 4.4 like this:

```
yum install gcc44 gcc44-c++
export CC="gcc44"
export CXX="g++44"
npm install -g level
```

reference: Level/levelup#224

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a `00npm.config` file in the `.ebextensions` folder. This clears the folder, sets the environment variables, and attempts to build again.

The file is:

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/50npm.sh" :
    mode: "000775"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash
      #==============================================================================
      # Copyright 2013 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
      #
      # Licensed under the Amazon Software License (the "License"). You may not use
      # this file except in compliance with the License. A copy of the License is
      # located at
      #
      #       http://aws.amazon.com/asl/
      #
      # or in the "license" file accompanying this file. This file is distributed on
      # an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, express or
      # implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions
      # and limitations under the License.
      #==============================================================================

      export HOME=/home/ec2-user
      export USERPROFILE=/home/ec2-user

      sudo rm -rf /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/bcrypt

      set -xe

      /opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py --action npm-install
```